# How to remove specific AAAA records from DNS using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dns, ipv6

I would like to remove all public IPv6 addresses from our DNS server, e.g. 2000:a61:10e3:8f01:: or 2003:d8:8bd7:c000:: but leave all link-local or site-local addresses e.g. fd00:: untouched.

I figured how to get a list of all AAAA records:

```
$DNSServer = "dns.domain.net"
$ZoneName = "domain.net"
$NodeDNS = $null
$NodeDNS = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $ZoneName -ComputerName $DNSServer -RRType AAAA -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Now the question is how to filter all those "public" records before invoking the Remove-DNSServerResourceRecord command?

```
Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $ZoneName -ComputerName $DNSServer -InputObject $NodeDNS -Force
```

would remove all AAAA records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this filter:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $ZoneName -ComputerName $DNSServer -RRType AAAA -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Where-Object {$_.RecordData.IPv6Address.IPAddressToString -match '2000:a61:10e3:8f01' -or `
$_.RecordData.IPv6Address.IPAddressToString -match '2003:d8:8bd7:c000' -and `
$_.RecordData.IPv6Address.IPAddressToString -notmatch '^fd00'
} | Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $ZoneName -WhatIf
```

The Sample uses Where-Object to filter returned data with specific string `-match` `-and` and `-notmatch` for further explanation see `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`

I've added the `-WhatIf` Parameter which show what it does before actually make the change, just to make sure you get the right results before deleting, if it's ok, remove the `-WhatIf`

Comment: Thank you for your input! That will work, however I cannot pass the filtered result to Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord. If I do it as suggested, I receive an exception:`+ Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -WhatIf
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (DnsServerResourceRecord:PSObject) [Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectMissingMandatory,Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord`

Comment: just add the `$ZoneName`, updated the answer and if it solve your problem vote/accept answer

Comment: I also had to add -ComputerName $DNSServer. Now it works!